# How to add section divider in navigation drawer using react navigation

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

Suppose I have five items in drawer navigation. I want to add separator after three items. How to add this using react-navigation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to use the `contentComponent` prop to make custom changes. Check out the [docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/drawer-navigator.html)

Comment: Care to elaborate? So far all my attempts have miserably failed An example would be a godsend

Answer (score 7):

As mentioned vonovak, you could achieve this by using `contentComponent` which allows complete customization of drawer. For this you will need to create custom component which will override default drawer. Code sample:

- Navigation Drawer

```
const NavigationDrawer = DrawerNavigator({
      screen1: { screen: Screen1 },
      screen2: { screen: Screen2 },
      screen3: { screen: Screen3 },
  }, {
      contentComponent: SideMenu
  })
```

- Custom component which overrides default drawer (DrawerContainer)

```
class SideMenu extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <ScrollView>
                    <Text
                        onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Screen1')}
                        style={styles.item}>
                        Page1
                    </Text>
                    // 'separator' line
                    <View
                        style={{
                        borderBottomColor: 'black',
                        borderBottomWidth: 1
                    }}/>
                    <Text
                        onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Screen2')}
                        style={styles.item}>
                        Page2
                    </Text>
                    <Text
                        onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Screen3')}
                        style={styles.item}>
                        Page3
                    </Text>
                </ScrollView>
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using DrawerItem component you can use `itemStyle` prop to add style as follows

```
const props = {
        itemStyle: {
            borderBottomWidth: 1,
            borderColor: '#E2E4E8',
        }
}

<DrawerItems {...props} />
```

You can also modify the style of container containing all items with
`itemsContainerStyle` prop.

Check official docs here.

- 3.x: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/3.x/drawer-navigator#contentoptions-for-draweritems
- 4.x: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/4.x/drawer-navigator#contentoptions-for-draweritems
- 5.x: DrawerContent is default drawer Item from v.5
  You can pass props to it using drawerContentOptions object in     Drawer.Navigator component.
  https://reactnavigation.org/docs/5.x/drawer-navigator#drawercontentoptions

  You can also pass custom drawer component using drawerContent prop.
  https://reactnavigation.org/docs/5.x/drawer-navigator#drawercontent
- 6.x: Custom component can be added using drawerContent prop
  https://reactnavigation.org/docs/drawer-navigator#drawercontent

  Style to drawerItem is changed to
  https://reactnavigation.org/docs/drawer-navigator#draweritemstyle

Answer (score 0):

1. Just add this code:

```
const Seperator = () => <View style={styles.separator} />;
```

at the top of your code that you want to have the section divider/separator on. If it's a navigation drawer, menu, categories or etc.

2. Add this styling prop:

```
  separator: {
    marginVertical: 8,
    borderBottomColor: "#737373",
    borderBottomWidth: StyleSheet.hairlineWidth
  }
```

3. Add section divider/separator between each section, menu, category block of code that you want to separate them like this:

```
//Block of code of first section/menu/category starts from here

   <Icon.Button
          name="th-large"
          raised={true}
          backgroundColor="#ffa500"
          size={30}
          onPress={() => {
            Linking.openURL("https://www.buymeacoffee.com/splendor");
          }}
        >
          <Text style={{ fontSize: 15 }}>
            Herat: The "Academy" of Prince Bay Sunghur (1420-1433)
          </Text>
        </Icon.Button>
        **<Seperator />**

//Block of code of first section/menu/category ends here

//Block of code of second section/menu/category starts from here

        <Icon.Button
          name="th-large"
          raised={true}
          backgroundColor="#ffa500"
          size={30}
          onPress={() => {
            Linking.openURL("https://www.buymeacoffee.com/splendor");
          }}
        >
          <Text style={{ fontSize: 15 }}>
            Venice, Istanbul, and Herat (15th Century)
          </Text>
        </Icon.Button>
        **<Seperator />**

//Block of code of second section/menu/category ends here

//Block of code of third section/menu/category starts from here

        <Icon.Button
          name="th-large"
          raised={true}
          backgroundColor="#ffa500"
          size={30}
          onPress={() => {
            Linking.openURL("https://www.buymeacoffee.com/splendor");
          }}
        >
          <Text style={{ fontSize: 15 }}>
            The Age of Bihzad of Herat (1465-1535)
          </Text>
        </Icon.Button>
        **<Seperator />**

//Block of code of thirds section/menu/category ends here
```