# react-navigation V2 - How can i make the custom drawer menu with different section?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I would like to have different sections in a drawer menu. Just like the followings picture.

[image]

How can I do that?

Comment: Check out [this](https://codeburst.io/custom-drawer-using-react-navigation-80abbab489f7) post

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add section divider in navigation drawer using react navigation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45126320/how-to-add-section-divider-in-navigation-drawer-using-react-navigation)